# How to auto adjust screen brightness?

Tags: power, brightness

I have the "automatic adjust brightness" option enabled on Power settings, but it doesn't seem work. I would like the display brightness to reduce automatically when the charger is unplugged.

Is there a config file that I can edit?

I have a Clevo N131BU with TLP and kernel 4.13 installed.

Comment: I just noticed this myself. Auto-adjust is enabled but it does not seem to have any  effect (Dell Inspiron N5010)

Answer (score 1):

You should check wether your current graphics card drivers are up-to-date. Moreover, disabling such drivers can help to see if the issue is fixed. If using the intel-based graphics card, you can use these commands to fix the issue. /etc/default/grub and add acpi osi=linux to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=. The run update-grup, it should work properly.